# ROS Answers SE migration: rosmake error

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I am trying to rosmake my package and get this configuration error:

```
    [rosmake-0] Finished <<< player ROS_NOBUILD in package player                                                                                                                      
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> diagnostic_msgs [ make ]                                                                                                                                  
[ rosmake ] All 21 lineseometry_msgs: 0.1 sec ] [ sensor_msgs: 0.1 sec ] [ nav_msgs: 0.1 sec ] [ diagnostic_msgs: 0.1 sec ]                             [ 4 Active 12/25 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  mkdir -p bin
  cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
  [rosbuild] Building package geometry_msgs
  Failed to invoke /opt/ros/fuerte/bin/rospack deps-manifests geometry_msgs
  [rospack] Error: package/stack geometry_msgs depends on non-existent package rosbagmigration
  
  
  CMake Error at /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:129 (message):
    
  
    Failed to invoke rospack to get compile flags for package 'geometry_msgs'.
    Look above for errors from rospack itself.  Aborting.  Please fix the
    broken dependency!
  
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:203 (rosbuild_invoke_rospack)
    CMakeLists.txt:12 (rosbuild_init)
  
  
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package geometry_msgs written to:
[ rosmake ]    /root/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130204-134741/geometry_msgs/build_output.log                 
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< geometry_msgs [FAIL] [ 0.09 seconds ]                                                                                                                     
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package geometry_msgs. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.                                                                   
[ rosmake ] All 21 lines
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  mkdir -p bin
  cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
  [rosbuild] Building package nav_msgs
  Failed to invoke /opt/ros/fuerte/bin/rospack deps-manifests nav_msgs
  [rospack] Error: package/stack geometry_msgs depends on non-existent package rosbagmigration
  
  
  CMake Error at /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:129 (message):
    
  
    Failed to invoke rospack to get compile flags for package 'nav_msgs'.  Look
    above for errors from rospack itself.  Aborting.  Please fix the broken
    dependency!
  
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:203 (rosbuild_invoke_rospack)
    CMakeLists.txt:12 (rosbuild_init)
  
  
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package nav_msgs written to:
[ rosmake ]    /root/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130204-134741/nav_msgs/build_output.log                           
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< nav_msgs [FAIL] [ 0.09 seconds ]                                                                                                                          
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package nav_msgs. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.                                                                        
[ rosmake ] All 21 lines
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  mkdir -p bin
  cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
  [rosbuild] Building package diagnostic_msgs
  Failed to invoke /opt/ros/fuerte/bin/rospack deps-manifests diagnostic_msgs
  [rospack] Error: package/stack diagnostic_msgs depends on non-existent package rosbagmigration
  
  
  CMake Error at /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:129 (message):
    
  
    Failed to invoke rospack to get compile flags for package
    'diagnostic_msgs'.  Look above for errors from rospack itself.  Aborting.
    Please fix the broken dependency!
  
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:203 (rosbuild_invoke_rospack)
    CMakeLists.txt:12 (rosbuild_init)
  
  
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package diagnostic_msgs written to:
[ rosmake ]    /root/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130204-134741/diagnostic_msgs/build_output.log             
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< diagnostic_msgs [FAIL] [ 0.09 seconds ]                                                                                                                   
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package diagnostic_msgs. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.                                                                 
[ rosmake ] All 21 lines
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  mkdir -p bin
  cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
  [rosbuild] Building package sensor_msgs
  Failed to invoke /opt/ros/fuerte/bin/rospack deps-manifests sensor_msgs
  [rospack] Error: package/stack geometry_msgs depends on non-existent package rosbagmigration
  
  
  CMake Error at /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:129 (message):
    
  
    Failed to invoke rospack to get compile flags for package 'sensor_msgs'.
    Look above for errors from rospack itself.  Aborting.  Please fix the
    broken dependency!
  
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:203 (rosbuild_invoke_rospack)
    CMakeLists.txt:12 (rosbuild_init)
  
  
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package sensor_msgs written to:
[ rosmake ]    /root/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130204-134741/sensor_msgs/build_output.log                     
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< sensor_msgs [FAIL] [ 0.10 seconds ]                                                                                                                       
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package sensor_msgs. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.                                                                     
[ rosmake ] Results:                                                                                                                                                               
[ rosmake ] Built 16 packages with 4 failures.                                                                                                                                     
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                                                                                                                            
[ rosmake ] /root/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130204-134741
```

Does anyone know what is wrong? Thanks in advance

Kind Regards,
Martin

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54247/rosmake-error/) by [MartinW](https://answers.ros.org/users/2868/martinw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 464 on 2013-02-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you're trying to mix `electric` and `fuerte`. All of your errors are referring to [rosbagmigration](http://ros.org/wiki/rosbagmigration) which has been moved to the [rosbag](http://ros.org/wiki/rosbag/migration) package as of `fuerte`.

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2013-02-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MartinW](https://answers.ros.org/users/2868/martinw/) on 2013-02-04**:
Yea this was exactly what was happening! Thank you for the help